# Using a for loop to replace string characters in a .NET C# Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, variables

I am new to .NET MVC, and come from PHP/Java/ActionScript.

The problem I have come across is with the .NET Model and `get{}`. I do not understand why my `Hyphenize` string will return the value of `SomeText` truncated to 64 characters, but without replacing any of the characters defined in the array.

Model -  This is supposed to replace certain characters in `SomeText` with a simple hyphen `-` :

```
    public string SomeText{ get; set;} // Unmodified string

    public string Hyphenize{ 
        get {
            //unwanted characters to replace
            string[] replace_items = {"#", " ", "!", "?", "@", "*", ",", ".", "/", "'", @"\", "=" };
            string stringbuild = SomeText.Substring(0, (SomeText.Length > 64 ? 64 : SomeText.Length));

            for (int i = 0; i < replace_items.Length; i++)
            {
                stringbuild.Replace(replace_items[i], "-");
            }

            return stringbuild;
        }

        set { }
    }
```

Alternatively, the method below does work correctly and will return the string with `" "` and `"#"` characters replaced. However, it bothers me that I am unable to understand why the for loop did not work.

```
    public string Hyphenize{ 
        get {
            //Replaces unwanted characters
            return SomeText.Substring(0, (SomeText.Length > 64 ? 64 : SomeText.Length)).Replace(" ", "-").Replace("#", "-");
        }

        set { }
    }
```

Ultimately I ended up with

```
return Regex.Replace(SomeText.Substring(0, (SomeText.Length > 64 ? 64 : SomeText.Length)).Replace("'", ""), @"[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "-").Replace("--", "-");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`string` is *immutable*, from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx):

> Strings are immutable--the contents of a string object cannot be changed after the object is created, although the syntax makes it appear as if you can do this.

so you need to have to assign again:

```
 stringbuild = stringbuild.Replace(replace_items[i], "-");
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not assigning the value of `Replace()` to anything. It returns its result, and does not modify the string that it operates on. (String's are immutable).